# Cryptocode: multiple items on arrow bbroracleqry(from/to) and how to place them

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, tikz-arrows, cryptocode

Hope some of you can help!

MWE:

```
\begin{bbrenv}{A}
    \begin{bbrbox}[name=$\mathcal{C}$]
        \pseudocode{%
            ((N,e),d) \leftarrow \gen(1^n)\\
            b \leftarrow^r \{0,1\}\\
            \enc((N,e),m_b) \rightarrow c_b = m_b^e \bmod N\\
            \\
            \\
            \\
            \text{Wenn } b'=b \quad \text{return } 1\\
            \text{sonst return } 0\\
        }
    \end{bbrbox}
    \begin{bbroracle}{OraA}
        \begin{bbrbox}[name=\A]
            \pseudocode{
                \\
            \\
            \\
            \text{Dann berechnet \A}\\
            \quad m_0^e, m_1^e\\
            \implies c_b = m_0^e \lor m_1^e\\
            \text{falls } c_b =m_0^e \quad b'=0\\
            \text{sonst } b'=1\\
            }
        \end{bbrbox}
    \end{bbroracle}
    \bbroracleqryto{top=$(Ne)$}
    \bbroracleqryfrom{top=$m_0m_1$}
    \bbroracleqryto{top=$c_b$}
    \bbroracle
```

Problem:

```
    \bbroracleqryto{top=$(Ne)$}
    \bbroracleqryfrom{top=$m_0m_1$}
    \bbroracleqryto{top=$c_b$}
    \bbroracleqryfrom{top=$b'$}
```

they should just show N,e and m_0, m_1 on the arrow ... but sadly I apparently can't just add a comma. And I want b' to be placed down to the line where "falls" is written by the attacker.

[image: Cryptocode problems]

Comment: To get a comma, try `\bbroracleqryfrom{top={$m_0,m_1$}}`...

Comment: works, thanks ... only thing missing now is the  skip

Comment: Use `\bbroracleqryspace{3.25\baselineskip}` before `\bbroracleqryfrom{top=$b'$}`.